# Issue rendering data within a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm attempting to render a list of footer items within a Function Component.

Here is my data:

```
export const footerLinks = [{
  "title": "Learn More",
  "data": [{
      id: 'news',
      name: 'News',
      to: '/news'
    },
    {
      id: 'faq',
      name: 'FAQ',
      to: '/faq'
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "Media",
  "data": [{
      id: 'media',
      name: 'Media Kit',
      to: '/media'
    },
    {
      id: 'media_enquiries',
      name: 'Media Enquiries',
      to: '/media_enquiries'
    }
  ]
}]
```

I import the data and attempt to output it in a `<ul>`. The `console.log` in the `MyListItems` function *does* output the expected values. However, after the `forEach`, logging `listItems` shows it is `undefined` and only an empty `<ul></ul>` makes it to the screen.

Any ideas what is going on here?

```
import { footerLinks } from '../site'

function MyListItems() {
  const listItems = footerLinks.forEach(section => {
    section.data.map(({id, name, to}) => {
      console.log(id, name, to);
      <li>{name}</li>
    })
  });

  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}

export function Footer() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyListItems />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything out of loop, means it will return `undefined`, use `map` instead

```
 const listItems = footerLinks.map(section => {
    return section.data.map(({id, name, to}) => {
      console.log(id, name, to);
      return <li>{name}</li>
    })
  });
```

[**forEach return value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value)